# Hard to read fonts and bad choice of colors

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

I just entered this site from stackoverflow. First thing I notice is bad choice of colors, and that fonts are hard to read. Is there a way to customize these? or perhaps you changing it?

Edit --
White background and black fonts, it hurts my eyes.
Fonts that look like handwriting are are to read.
Overall look of website isn't attractive, maybe use warm colors? right now site looks dead.

Comment: SO uses black on white as well.

Comment: Very many sites and apps use black on white, and I'm aware, I'm just saying I "think" the way you use it isn't good, and I wonder why would you people down vote me? May be you mean requests/suggestions shouldn't be made?

Comment: Downvotes on meta mean that people disagree with your suggestion.

Comment: [Black on white is the most readable of all colour schemes](http://www.laurenscharff.com/research/survreslts.html). If it hurts your eyes, then something's wrong with your eyes.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to customise the look of the site is via user scripts.

If you check [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) there are some posted there.

If you have positive suggestions then please edit them into your question. The designer, Jin, checks the sites from time to time and will see this question.

Answer (score 2):

> White background and black fonts, it
>   hurts my eyes.

I don't see how you'd have a problem with this site but not Stack Overflow especially since Programmers.se' text vs background has less harsh contrast than SO's.

> Fonts that look like handwriting are
>   are to read.

The hand-written font is only used on meta text, such as the navigation text and sidebar head text. You don't "read" these text, you simply "scan" them.

> Overall look of website isn't
>   attractive, maybe use warm colors?
>   right now site looks dead.

Like the other two points you've made, this is purely subjective. I typically ignore subjective design requests based purely on personal preferences. If I try to please everyone, I end up pleasing no one.